# How to select entities by latest date with date being part of composite PK?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, composite-primary-key

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
public class TDInvestment {

  @Id
  private String tdName;

  @Id
  private LocalDate readingDate;

  //more attributes
}
```

Knowing I have a unique entity identified by `String tdName` and `LocalDate readingDate`, how can I select all latest entities(using Hibernate HQL or native SQL)? I know I can use `... order by readingDate desc;` to have the latest rows on top, but how can I select only the latest row of each unique `tdName`?

**UPDATE**

I tried using

```
  select tdName, max(readingDate)
    from table
group by tdName;
```

and it works only when table has only this 2 columns. How can I make it work when it has more non unique columns?

Example(dd/MM/yyyy):

```
tdName       readingDate  unitPrice  other non unique Columns
abc          10/02/2018   214125.34  ...
def          25/01/2012   134.21312  ...
abc          21/11/2015   54983.23   ...
def          19/07/2011   0.2374     ...
abc          01/03/2002   83271.1    ...
ghi          11/10/1950   12         ...
```

and my query should return:

```
tdName       readingDate  unitPrice  other non unique Columns
abc          10/02/2018   214125.34  ...
def          25/01/2012   134.21312  ...
ghi          11/10/1950   12         ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I discovered my answer was pretty close to the other answer. The complete select query to return all fields is as below:

```
        select
        t1.name,
        t1.max,
        t2.due_date,
        t2.fixed_rate,
        t2.unit_price,
        t2.reading_time
    from (select
            t2.name,
            max(t2.reading_date)
            from td t2
            where
            t2.due_date > now() 
            group by t2.name) t1,
            td t2
    where
        t1.name = t2.name
        and t1.max = t2.reading_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE o
WHERE o.readingDate = (
    SELECT MAX(e.readingDate) FROM TABLE e
    WHERE e.tdName = o.tdName
);
```